# How can I make my neo4j request faster on large research, then merge result with new node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, cypher-3.1

I am currently having a performance issue on a Neo4J request.

Here is the problem. I need to find users in the database from a large list. To do this, the uniqCode must match, OR the name and location (zip) must match.

Then I want to be able to merge this user with a node I create.

The query below works but it takes between 20 and 30 seconds for a list of 30 users and on real case, it will be necessary to pass a list of 5000 to 10000 users.

I specify that I indexed the uniqCode and the name of the users nodes.

```
UNWIND $users as row
    MATCH (u:User)
    WHERE u.uniqCode = row.uniqCode
    OR (
        apoc.text.clean(u.name) = row.name
        AND EXISTS ((u)-[:IS]->(:Zip {name:row.zip}))
    )
    MERGE (u)<-[:IS]-(a:ParallelUser {id:row.uuid, name: u.name, uniqCode: row.uniqCode})
    RETURN {name: a.name, uniqCode: a.uniqCode, id: a.id} AS ParallelUser
```

with params look like

```
[{uniqCode: "1234", name: "John Doe", zip: "1234", uuid: "1234"}, ...]
```

Thank you in advance for your help...

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you could use an index for the `MATCH` clause in your query. You can check to see if the query planner is using any indexes by running the query and prepending with `PROFILE`. Feel free to post the results back here for more detailed discussion.

The [query tuning documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/) might be helpful to you.

I found [this free course](https://neo4j.com/graphacademy/training-cqt-40/enrollment/) enlightening.

You won't be able to use an index on `u.name` if you have to wrap it in the `apox.text.clean()` function. Can you run that function on the property before you store it, or else create a new `cleanName` property? Then you could create an index that includes that property.

On the `MERGE` portion of your query, I wonder if all three properties of `ParallelUser` are required to uniquely identify the node? If the `id` alone is sufficient, then you can rewrite the `MERGE` portion this way:

```
MERGE (u)<-[:IS]-(a:ParallelUser {id:row.uuid})
SET a.name = u.name, a.uniqCode = row.uniqCode
```